# django os.path.dirname(__file__)

Tags: python, django, operating-system

I am doing exercises from book: 
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html

and I have problem with this code:

```
import os

print __file__
print os.path.dirname(__file__)
print os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

It shold print dir names. Instead of that it prints first line ( filename)
but 2nd and 3rd line are also printed but empty.

I get this behavior with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

EDIT: with this code i get absolute path with `os.path.dirname(__file__)`:

```
import os
import django
import settings

print settings.BASE_DIR
```

What is the difference if the same code is imporeted from settings.py and coded directly?

Comment: both your answers works. i am interested why in the book is mentioned just os.path.dirname(__file__)
is it error or there is some underlying reason?

Answer (score 1):

The `__file__` value in the *main script* can be relative to the current working directory. Use [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to make it absolute first:

```
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the absolute path of the directory where the program resides **which is what you want** I believe.

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This is the parent directory of the program

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'some_directory')
```

This is the abbreviated directory where the program resides

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```